# Problems with Library (jUnique) after building a jar-file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm creating Java code with the IntelliJ-idea using several external libraries downloading the depending jar-files and add them under "Project setting" -> "Libraries".

One of them is jUnique (http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/).

In IntelliJ everything works fine while coding and debugging. But after I built an jar-file (I have no experience with that), the dependency seems to be "broken", while the other libraries still working.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/sauronsoftware/junique/AlreadyLockedException
```

Comment: `and add them under "Project setting" -> "Libraries".` If you want to use them in project - add them in [module's dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html) in [**Dependencies tab**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies.html) not just `"Project setting" -> "Libraries"` Then when building the [jar artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-jar-from-modules-dialog.html) - check that these libraries are included into it.

Comment: Thank you. But obviously they are added there automatically and checked as "Compile". I think the classpath or my understanding of it is wrong :-(